# Transforming vector to matrix

Tags: python

I have vector `y` with n values.

I want to create matrix that will have following form

```
y = [[1, y_1, y_1^2, ...,y_1^n], 
    [1, y_2, y_2^2, ...,y_2^n] ... [1, y_n, y_n^2, ...,y_n^n] ]
```

Comment: You should consider using `numpy` package. There is a useful builtin [`numpy.power()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension is a natural way to proceed:

```
[[pow(yi,n) for n in range(1 + len(y))] for yi in y]
```

For `y = [1,2,3,4]` this produces

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16],
[1, 3, 9, 27, 81],
[1, 4, 16, 64, 256]]
```

Comment: Actually, `range(len(y) + 1)`, according to their original specification.

Comment: @FrankYellin Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: @Alena Not sure what you mean, it should be `n x (n+1)` (matching your problem description) rather than `(n+1) x n`

Answer (score 1):

```
y = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
n = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
matrix = [[yi**ni for ni in n] for yi in y]
```